# Django, Tiny_MCE break my css style in admin flatpage and dont appear

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

im trying to use the Tiny MCE editor in my FlatPages, but the Editor dont appear and the css of the add form in flatpage is broken.

im using in this way:

url.py

```
(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': 'e:/wamp/www/diligencia/src/tiny_mce/jscripts/tiny_mce/'}),
```

template:

template overriding : templates/admin/flatpages/flatpage/change_form.html

code in my template change_form.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "simple"
});
</script>
```

i want to know where is the problem :(

Thanks
Regards,
Asinox

Comment: Thanks is working with this link data

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you 've worked this out by now but I think that it 's just a typo and you need to change:

```
    'e:/wamp/www/diligencia/src/tiny_mce/jscripts/tiny_mce/'
```

to

```
    'e:/wamp/www/diligencia/src/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/'
```

The later is the path that is stored inside the tinyMCE archive.

Comment: thanks for replay Yorgos, but is working yet :), just with a media JS called textarea.js :)